# Reuse ajax variable in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ajax, coffeescript

I have a part of my backbone application that requires a user confirmation when I try to insert a value through my WebApi.

I have this code:

```
@xhr = $.post '/api/entity/create', @data

@xhr.done (resp) =>
    if @xhr.status == 202
        # Some code for confirmation box
         @data.Force = true
         @xhr = $.post '/api/entity/create', @data # Problem is here

@xhr.fail (resp) =>
    # Code for error
```

When I force the insertion I don't go through @xhr.done after my WebApi call

Do you have any clue why it doesn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because that's a new `@xhr`, and the callbacks are attached to the old. You can move it to another method and reuse it (I imagine you have a class around the code):

```
post: ->

  @xhr = $.post '/api/entity/create', @data

  @xhr.done (resp) =>
    if @xhr.status == 202
      # Some code for confirmation box
      @data.Force = true
      @post()

  @xhr.fail (resp) =>
    # Code for error
```